# How to create a (left/right) "\semicirc"?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, circles

I would like to have commands `\leftsemicirc`, `\rightsemicirc` in math mode which produce left/right semicircles the size of `\circ`.

The best approximation of a solution I am aware is to use `bbding` and writing `\text{HalfCircleLeft}`, however this is solid and most importantly it's too big.

Thanks!

Comment: what are the symbols supposed to represent?

Comment: open or closed? Unicode provides closed half circles:  ◖◗ which you could use with an appropriate font...

Comment: @Apparently open (or not filled) as the OP 'complains' aobut `HalfCircleLeft being solid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually draw these using the `graphics` package and `\put`, `\oval` and `\line` commands. I understand you don't want filled semicircles, but I didn't know if you wanted open or closed. Both appear below. Also, I included a `\newcirc` so it is exactly the same size as the semicircles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\leftsemicirc}{\put(3.5,2.5){\oval(4,4)[l]}\phantom{\circ}}
\newcommand{\rightsemicirc}{\put(1.5,2.5){\oval(4,4)[r]}\phantom{\circ}}
\newcommand{\cleftsemicirc}{\put(3.5,2.5){\oval(4,4)[l]}\put(3.5,.5){\line(0,1){4}}\phantom{\circ}}
\newcommand{\crightsemicirc}{\put(1.5,2.5){\oval(4,4)[r]}\put(1.5,.5){\line(0,1){4}}\phantom{\circ}}
\newcommand{\newcirc}{\put(2.5,2.5){\oval(4,4)}\phantom{\circ}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$A\circ B$\\
$A\mathbin{\leftsemicirc} B$\\
$A\mathbin{\rightsemicirc} B$\\
$A\mathbin{\cleftsemicirc} B$\\
$A\mathbin{\crightsemicirc} B$\\
$A\mathbin{\newcirc} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be made automatically scalable?